# Is public IP we get in pod different from Node's public IP it is running?

Tags: kubernetes

I have pods running on different nodes. But when I execute the command
`curl -s checkip.dyndns.org`, I am getting the same public IP for all. So, is the pod's public IP different from the public IP of the node it is running?

Also, when I execute the command `kubectl get nodes -o wide`, I get `EXTERNAL-IP` as `<none>` and there is only `INTERNAL-IP`.

I actually need the node's public IP address to access Kubernetes **NodePort** service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`...when I execute the command curl -s checkip.dyndns.org, I am getting the same public IP for all.`

That's your NAT public IP.

`I actually need the node's public IP address...`

The node needs to run in a subnet that allows direct (no NAT) Internet access and have public IP assigned. You can find this info on your cloud provider console; or in the node run `ip addr show` to see all IP(s) assigned to the node.